# binary variable does not correspond with category numbers

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a new binary variable based on several categorical variables. I have tried multiple ways to do this including base or if else commands, and mutate case when from dyplyr. When I make the new variable, the number does not add up to how many were in the categories in the original variables.

```
data<- c("ket"(1,0,0,0,1,0)
   c("weed"(0,1,1,1,0,0)
   c("speed"(1,0,0,1,0,0)
   c("meth"(0,0,0,1,0,0)

data<-data%>%
  mutate(druguse = case_when(
    (weed==1 | ket==1 | meth==1 | speed==1) ~1,
    (TRUE ~0)))
```

the new variable should add up to how many answered one in each category, but the number in my new variable is a lot lower.

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid having to write out an explicit `case_when` here, by taking the `sign` of the sum of each row. This will be 0 if the whole row is zero, and one otherwise.

```r
data %>% mutate(druguse = sign(rowSums(.)))
#>   ket weed speed meth druguse
#> 1   1    0     1    0       1
#> 2   0    1     0    0       1
#> 3   0    1     0    0       1
#> 4   0    1     1    1       1
#> 5   1    0     0    0       1
#> 6   0    0     0    0       0
```

---

**Data**

```r
data <- structure(list(ket = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), weed = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0), speed = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), meth = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

data
#>   ket weed speed meth
#> 1   1    0     1    0
#> 2   0    1     0    0
#> 3   0    1     0    0
#> 4   0    1     1    1
#> 5   1    0     0    0
#> 6   0    0     0    0
```